Generalization of Inverse Euler-Angles
Let $R_X(\alpha)$, $R_Y(\beta)$, $R_Z(\gamma)$ be 3 3D-rotations around the $X$-, $Y$-, $Z$-axis respectively.
Then the resulting rotation $R_r$ = $R_X(\alpha) R_Y(\beta) R_Z(\gamma)$ can be any 3D rotation. And it is also possible to calculate $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ from $R_r$ if those axes are known. Here is how.
I am interested in the more general case where the axes are orthogonal to the previous rotation's axis.
Let $R_r$ = $R_1(\alpha) R_2(\beta) R_3(\gamma)$.
Let $a_1$ be the axis of rotation for the rotation $R_1(\alpha)$.
Let $a_1$ be orthogonal to $a2$, i.e. $a_1 \cdot a_2 = 0$ and $a_2$ be orthogonal to $a3$, i.e. $a_2 \cdot a_3 = 0$ but in general $a_1$ NOT orthogonal $a_3$.
I have the problem reformulated as follows:
$$R_r = R_Z(\alpha) R_{12} R_Z(\beta) R_{23} R_Z(\gamma)$$
Where $R_Z(\alpha)$, $R_Z(\beta)$, $R_Z(\gamma)$ are unknown rotations around the Z axis $(0,0,1)$. $R_{12}$ and $R_{23}$ are two known rotations which rotate the Z axis into the XY-plane, i.e.
$$(R_{12} \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}) \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = 0$$ and $$ (R_{23} \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}) \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = 0$$
Given $R_r$, $R_{12}$ and $R_{23}$, how can I calculate the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$?
(Note: I have all rotations in Unit Quaternion representation, but any other representation is fine, if beneficial for solving the problem.)
